# Show total sum value of the id from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Display the total sum of all id value after the text "Total sum of all id value is:"
The id value is from the API data.

Problem:
I do not know how to do it and is it possible to do it?

Info:
I'm a newbie in React JS

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f7chuv?

Thank you!

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          data
        }));
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data &&
            this.state.data.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id} id={user.id}>
                {user.id}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <div>
          Total sum of all id value is: 
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: your best bet is to use the js ```reduce()``` to get the sum and then put that value where you need it in your render method ```<div>
          Total sum of all id value is: {this.state.data.reduce(what you want to sum here)}
        </div>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways this can be accomplished, but you need to effectively loop over the data array and accumulate/add the IDs up. You can do this with [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
Total sum of all id value is: {this.state.data && this.state.data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.id, 0)}
```

Another alternative is at the first line inside of `render()`:

```js
let idSum = 0;
for (let i = 0; this.state.data && i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
    idSum += this.state.data[i].id;
}
```

Then you can output the `idSum`:

```
Total sum of all id value is: {idSum}
```

Comment: It'd be better to store this in state instead of calculating it on every render

Comment: @Samathingamajig That's unnecessary. It's much better to calculate/compute state when you can. If it's a performance problem then it can always be memoized.

Comment: @Samathingamajig For more info on what I mean, this is a good blog post: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-sync-state-derive-it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map/reduce` and display the result

```
      {this.state.data && (
        <>
          Total sum of all id value is:{' '}
          {this.state.data.map(itm => itm.id).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)}
        </>
      )}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qd46mi)

Comment: It'd be better to store this in state instead of calculating it on every render. Also you don't need to map it before you reduce, just say `a + b.id`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution would be to implement it in your `then` callback after the successful fetch.

Here's an adaptation of your component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      data: null,
      idSum: null // <========== HERE 
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const idSum = data.reduce((tot, next) => tot + next.id, 0); // <========= HERE
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          data,
          idSum  // <========= HERE
        }));
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <ul>
          {this.state.data &&
            this.state.data.map(user => (
              <li key={user.id} id={user.id}>
                {user.id}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <div>
          Total sum of all id value is: {this.state.idSum}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can find more info about `reduce` method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce